# AspectJ and NoSuchBeanDefinitionException at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, aspectj

I'm trying to use AspectJ, my project was working correctly. But when I try to use AspectJ the injection isn't working correctly. If I don't use AspectJ, it works again.

I included on my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

My configuration file:

```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/> 

        <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="es.rooms.db.spring.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="es.rooms.util" />

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="es.rooms.util.LoggingAspect" />
```

I'm using annotations to my classes:

```
@Repository("RoomDAO")
public class RoomDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport implements IRoomDAO{

    @Autowired
    private PlayerDAO playerDAO;
```

I don't know if I have to scan my AspectJ class, I did anyway. I tried to mark as required=false the PlayerDAO and I could check that LoggingAspect is called but when RoomDAO is going to call to PlayerDAO I got a NullPointException. Why can't spring inject PlayerDAO when I use AspectJ?

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {



    @Before("execution(* es.rooms.db.spring.dao.*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!logBefore() is running! ->" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());        
        System.out.println("******");
    }
```

This is the error:

```
04-jun-2013 11:36:46 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@61acfa31: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,playerDAO,RoomDAO,userDAO,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,manageRooms,messagesGcm,transactionManager,logAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RoomDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.rooms.db.spring.dao.PlayerDAO es.rooms.db.spring.dao.RoomDAO.playerDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [es.rooms.db.spring.dao.PlayerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at es.rooms.server.RoomsServer.<init>(RoomsServer.java:23)
    at es.rooms.server.RoomsServer.main(RoomsServer.java:61)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.rooms.db.spring.dao.PlayerDAO es.rooms.db.spring.dao.RoomDAO.playerDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [es.rooms.db.spring.dao.PlayerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 14 more
```

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I fixed it adding

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

But, i don't know why that happens, I appreciate if someone could explain me.

Comment: One thing I see that might effect it is that your autowire should use the interface IPlayerDAO, not the implementation.  I believe when Spring creates the proxy, it uses the interface to build it and then calls the instantiated class.  I am basing this observation solely on stack traces I have seen in my own code, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh!! thanks a lot!, you were right. I deleted the autoproxy tag and it's working.

Comment: @CodeChimp: thank you very much for the solution, I had the same issue, spent few days going nuts and finally found this post.... :)

Answer (score 2):

from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the
>   proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred
>   whenever you have a choice).
>
> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface
>   then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces
>   implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object
>   does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.
>
> If you want to force the use of CGLIB proxying (for example, to proxy
>   every method defined for the target object, not just those implemented
>   by its interfaces) you can do so. 
>   ....
>   To force the use of CGLIB proxies set the value of the
>   proxy-target-class attribute of the  element to true:

So, you have turned on the CGLIB proxy for all your classes. Read the whole page for more information - it's important background info to using spring AOP. Some interesting and different things happen when you use CGLIB (all documented on the above link) - you're better off following the Spring conventions if you can. i.e. if you autowire a class, give it an interface and a null constructor.